# Ember.Object.create removes function from my original object

Tags: ember.js

I'm using complex javascript object that I want to wrap into Ember.Object.create so I can benefit of the binding on properties. However, when I create my ember object, I loose all functions that I had in my initial object but all the properties are transferred.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/88/

The introduce function which is part of the original object is lost after the Ember.Object.create. Is there a way to keep the prototypes function while keeping the benefits of Ember.Object.create.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your example is referencing an undefined variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ember's bindings without using the Ember object system.

Here's an example of using `Ember.bind()` to setup bindings to other objects. `Ember.run.sync()` calls are necessary to sync the bindings after binding setup and property changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/95/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also found out that I could create an empty object and extend it afterward. This keeps my prototyped functions working. Do you think it's a good idea? http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/104/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to really achieve. I would advice against trying to merge plain JS objects and Ember objects. Can you provide a more detailed example?